# vue-i18n fallback not working when default language is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, locale, vue-i18n

I am trying to change the language of my website based on users chrome default language. Currently I only have an english.js file however, I set a fallback to the english file. However if I change default language to anything other than english. I get an error stating that "locales'./locales/' + navigator.language.split('-')[0] + '.js'" is not a function.

```
import fallback from './locales/en';
let current = {};
const locales = import.meta.glob('./locales/*.js'); // the *.js should default to en.js if a fr.js is not found in my locale folder.
```

```
locales['./locales/' + navigator.language.split('-')[0] + '.js']()
.then(c => {
  current = c.default;
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
.finally(_ => {
  const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: current,
    fallbackLocale: fallback,
    fallbackWarn: false,
    missingWarn: false,
    messages: {
      current,
      fallback
    }
  });
  app.use(i18n);
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

Comment: Well your variables contains everything since you do a glob. Simply check the myLocales variables to see if the locale you are looking for exist

Comment: @Lk77 thanks for the reply I provided a bit more info based on new error appearing.

Comment: You need to check if it exist before calling it, wrap in a `if(locales.hasOwnProperty('./locales/' + navigator.language.split('-')[0] + '.js'))` otherwise use english.js in the else

Comment: @Lk77 ok great, how do I keep it as a function while implementing the if/else?

Comment: This error is happening because you don't have that language's file. Also, agreed with @Lk77, to check existence before access.

Comment: @NehaSoni the thing is I want it to fallback to english if the file doesnt exist but its not working. Would the if/else fix that?

Comment: @perrotss it will fix it, because you won't get into the if, but into the else, with a call to enligh.js function instead. You could put the if/else before the function call : `let fn = locales['./locales/en.js']; if(locales.hasOwnProperty('./locales/' + navigator.language.split('-')[0] + '.js')) { fn = locales['./locales/' + navigator.language.split('-')[0] + '.js'] }  fn().then()`. In the end you will always have a fn function you can call. You set up the variable as english function by default, and override only if user locale is found

Comment: @Lk77 it works!! thanks so much! please submit your answer so i can accept it as a response.